# Inaccurate results using mod operator in python

Tags: python, numpy, operators

I'm having trouble in a condition i want in a if statement. I want to check if a variable(float type), like 0.9,  is multiple of 0.1.

I had this code:
`(t * dt) % 0.1 == 0`

I've tried the modulo operator but gave me inaccurate results. For example 0.3 is not a multiple of 0.1. Can you help me?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?rq=3

Comment: @Guy that doesn't fully answer the question since it's a numpy array here (I doubt using `Decimal` would be a viable approach)

Comment: i understood the problem. can you recommend another way i can check if a variable is a multiple of 0.1?

Comment: @mariami you can use `a = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3]) ; n = 0.1 ; m = a%n ; out = np.isclose(m, 0) | np.isclose(m, n)`

Comment: @mozway the OP tagged the question as numpy, but I don't see any other evidence this is really a numpy question. He/she even say *variable(float type), like 0.9, is multiple of 0.1.*.